# Break long word in tabular

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

I have a long word inside my tabular I need to break. The other rows and columns look perfect, but since this is only 1 word, the actual word overlaps on the other column. Not ideal.

Is there a SIMPLE fix? Basically here's how I make the tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline

Header 
& 
Header 2\\


\hline
Marketingdivisiontesttesttest  
&
Some more text\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

Microsoft Word breaks the word easily.

Comment: You don't really give us enough information to address the issue.  Could you provide the code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Added an example of what I mean.

Comment: `Marketingdivision\-testtesttest  `

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Seems very... odd to do it that way, right? Isn't there a simple way of saying "when the word hits the right border of this table, break it into a new line"?

Comment: TeX's paragraph setting routines require the existence of breakpoints.  Obviously spaces between words are the common place to find them.  What I suggested is manually telling TeX how to break a long non-word.  If it can't find a rational place to break text, it won't.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hmm that's a shame. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: tex won't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph.  there are ways of fooling it by forcing a space at the beginning, then doing an explicit backup but i don't have an example at hand.  a more brute-force approach is to insert the breakpoint yourself; in the past i've done it by defining `\def\hybrk{-\break}` and inserting that in the appropriate place in the problem word.  (this was used when plain tex was the only option; i'm sure someone can convert it to the proper latex form.)

Comment: Simply put `\hspace{0pt}` in front of the word. `\hspace{0pt}Marketingdivisiontesttesttest`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first word in a paragraph isn't hyphenated. Use `\hspace{0pt}` or `lualatex` whichwill hyphenate also the first word.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|P{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
        \hline
        Header 
        & 
        Header 2\\
        \hline
        Marketingdivisiontesttesttest  
        &
        Some more text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this quite simply is to add `\newline`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
Header 
& 
Header 2\\
\hline
Marketingdivision-\newline testtesttest  
&
Some more text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't scale that well to be honest.

Comment: @Snorlax After the first word the table breaks the lines automatically, so you would only have to use this a max of once every cell.

Answer (score 0):

That the first word in a paragraph is not hyphenated is true for TeX, pdfTeX, and XeTeX. LuaTeX behaves differently, there the first word can also be hyphenated.

The example comes from a duplicate [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362661/16967):

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
A LongHorribleAndPointlessMess & ALongHorribleAndPointlessMess \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]