# Auto line break with very long word within table

Tags: tables, numbering, line-breaking

I am trying to break a very very long number, 128 in length, to fit into a table cell so it won't go over the page.

I've looked up methods using `longtabu`, tabular with `p{5cm}` commend, `\makecell`, `\parbox{}`, `\multicolumn` with `p{5cm}`, but non of those works. It seems like they only line break at "space" but does not line break one whole word, in my case is number.

I know it is possible to manually break line with `\\` or `\newline`, but this doesn't seem practical in the long-run as I need to manually change this as the format of my document may change depending on the requirements given to me.

The only way I have in mind now, is to screenshot the long numbers into a figure, and insert it into the table. But if there is a better solution, I would like to use it.

Code that I use to `longtabu` attempt

```
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    |X[1,c]
    |X[10,l]|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Head 1} & 
    \textbf{Head 2} 
    \\ \hline
    12:18:52  & this is a description for the event \\\hline
    12:18:52  & this is a description for the event \\\hline
    12:18:52  & this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event \\\hline
    12:18:52  & 11111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777778888888888888888\\\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

[image]

Using `p{}`

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|}
  This text will be wrapped & Some more text \\\hline
  this & 11111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777778888888888888888\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]
Herbert solution at [Break long word in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338478/break-long-word-in-tabular)
[image]

Comment: thanks for all of your answers, tried Mico and Bernard's they worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could load the `xurl` package and encase the long number in a `\url{...}` "wrapper".

(The following code uses a `tabularx` environment since I'm not familiar with `longtabu`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,xurl}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document} 
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lX @{}}
\hline
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} \\ 
\hline
12:18:52  & this is a description for the event \\
\hline
12:18:52  &
\url{11111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777778888888888888888}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice (+1)!! Is it compatible with `longtable`? Because, I am not able to use this nice example in `longtable` environment `:-/`.

Comment: @Raaja - I can see no reason why the `xurl` package/`\url` macro setup can't be used in other settings. Since `longtable` doesn't allow the `X` column type (at least not directly), one would need to replace the `X` column with a `p` column with a suitably chosen width. (Aside: The `X` column type is, in fact, nothing but a `p` column, with LaTeX performing the width-related calculations.)

Comment: I didn't knew this info. I will play with it, If I must need further clarificatoins, I will ping you via chat `;-)`.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution with  `seqsplit`, `xltabular`, which combines the functionalities of `longtable` and `tabularx`, and `makecell` to define some vertical padding of cells in the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit, makecell, xltabular}

\begin{document}

{\setcellgapes[b]{3pt}
\setcellgapes[t]{2pt}\makegapedcells
\noindent\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}%|
    \hline
    \textbf{Head 1} &
    \textbf{Head 2}
    \\ \hline
    12:18:52 & this is a description for the event \\\hline
    12:18:52 & this is a description for the event \\\hline
    12:18:52 & this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event this is a description for the event \\\hline
    12:18:52 & \seqsplit{ 111111111111111111111111111111111111112222222222222222222222222222222222222222233333333333333333333333333333333333444444444444444444444%
    55555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777778888888888888888} \\\hline
\end{xltabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the number is not in the list of words that tex uses to determine possible break points of words, but one can manually add them by placing `\-` at each point where the number can be broken across lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|}
  This text will be wrapped & Some more text \\\hline
  this & 1\-111\-111\-1111\-111\-111\-11\-111\-111\-111\-111\-111\-111\-122\-22\-222\-22\-222\-22\-22\-222\-22\-22\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```