# Automatically break long word to fit tabular column width

Tags: tables, line-breaking

What is the best way to

1. Set a column's width to fit the longest word of a column heading?
2. If a word is too long, automatically break it to fit column margins?

MWE:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Flu &  Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis &  Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism\\
    \hline
    x & y & z\\
    \hline& 
\end{tabular}
```

There is an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338478/break-long-word-in-tabular) but it requires lualatex. I am interested in a solution using XeLateX (which is a requirement for me) and, if possible, pdflatex.

--- EDIT

This comes closer to what I need. drawback: tabulary does not take the longest word as minimum width, but the column words. Workaround: manually adjust some columns:

```
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|V{2cm}|J|J|}
    \hline
    Flu &  Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis &  Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism\\
    \hline
    x & y & z\\
    \hline& 
\end{tabulary}
```

Comment: If according to 1) columns are as wide as their longest word , then no word is too long to fit into the column and 2) cannot happen. But the table itself can too wide so that it sticks out into the margin and/or does not fit on the page/paper.  You have three/several columns. Assume each column holds a longest word. Assume without hyphenation the total width of all columns exceeds the width of the text that surrounds the table at the top and at the bottom. Which columns' widths shall be decreased to what extend to be shorter than the longest word in the column?

Comment: The package [varwidth](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) provides an environment `varwidth` which is similar to the environment `minipage`. With `varwidth` the argument for the width of the box is a maximum - the width will be smaller if stuff fits into the box anyway without having an additional linebreak in its content. You can define column-types similar to `p` based on `varwidth`.

Comment: A table cell that can hold multiple lines must be defined with `p` and a specified width.  It is best set up to be ragged right.  By a quirk of (La)TeX, hyphenation cannot occur in the first word of such a cell; this can be overcome by starting the cell with `\hspace*{0pt}`.  After that, hyphenation can proceed according to the built-in hyphenation rules, limiting each segment to what fits within the specified width.

Comment: In chat my attention was drawn towards the package [tabulary](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) by David Carlisle. This package might provide an approach to what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to
>
> 1. Set a column's width to fit the longest word of a column heading?
> 2. If a word is too long, automatically break it to fit column margins?

Without any extra package? Use a length name and set a certain length to the name. Use the name in column specification, such as `p{\mycolumnwidth}`. In case a column needs some constraints such as upper bound,  let's say `0.4\textwidth`, you have to test it and reduce the length if it exceeds the upper bound.

I think this needs to be done per separate column, hence you may need separate length names and this is likely going to be rather tedious in more complex tables. You might be better off loosing your constrains and apply one of the available packages.

Anyway, you could do something around the lines

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}

\newlength\cwleft
\newlength\cwright
\NewDocumentCommand\setlenvar{mmm}{%
    % #1 - text
    % #2 - max length (upper bound) 
    % #3 - length name
    \settowidth{#3}{#1}
    \IfValueT{#2}{\ifdim \the#3>#2 \setlength{#3}{#2}\fi}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
%%% Set a table for the longest word with contraints
\setlenvar{Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis}%
    {0.4\textwidth}{\cwleft}
\setlenvar{Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism}%
    {0.3\textwidth}{\cwright}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c| C{\cwleft}| C{\cwright}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bf Name}
            & \multicolumn{1}{P{\cwleft}|}{\bf Column left}
            & \multicolumn{1}{P{\cwright}|}{\bf Column right} \\
        \hline
        Flu & Pneumonoultramicroscopic\-silicovolcanoconiosis & Pseudopseudohypo\-parathyroidism \\
        x & y & z \\
        A & Short text & Short text \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


%%% Set a table for the certain word constraints omitted
\setlenvar{Short text}{}{\cwleft}
\setlenvar{Short text}{}{\cwright}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c| C{\cwleft}| C{\cwright}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bf Name}
            & \multicolumn{1}{P{\cwleft}|}{\bf Column left}
            & \multicolumn{1}{P{\cwright}|}{\bf Column right} \\
        \hline
        Flu & Pneu\-mono\-ultra\-micro\-scopic\-sili\-covol\-cano\-coniosis & Pseudo\-pseudo\-hypo\-para\-thyro\-idism \\
        x & y & z \\
        A & Short text & Short \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]